# Drawing gradient on canvas

Tags: css, html5-canvas

How can I draw the following alpha gradient (see example image) on a html canvas?

Vertical White -> Black, with 45deg transparency bottom left -> top right.

Note: I need to draw this, not simply reference a background image.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use at least 2 gradients.

- gray extending vertically from left and rightward,
- black extending horizontally from bottom and upward

**Example code and a Demo:**

*Time doesn't permit tweaking this demo to exactly fit your example*

[image]

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var iw, ih, cw, ch;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = start;
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/transparency%20grid.png";

function start() {
  iw = cw = canvas.width = img.width;
  ih = ch = canvas.height = img.height;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

  // make gray gradient
  var gray = fillGradient(0, ch, cw, ch / 2, 'rgb(50,50,50)', 'transparent');
  // make black gradient
  var black = fillGradient(0, ch, 0, ch * .75, 'black', 'transparent');
}

function fillGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1, color0, color1) {
  var g = ctx.createLinearGradient(x0, y0, x1, y1);
  g.addColorStop(0.00, color0);
  g.addColorStop(1.00, color1);
  ctx.fillStyle = g;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cw, ch);
  return (g);
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```